# Mercurial move bookmark to old commit

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I currently have something looks like this:

```
@  changeset:   4
|  bookmark:    A
|  bookmark:    B
|  tag:         tip
|
o  changeset:   3
|  -
|
o  changeset:   2
|  -
|
o  changeset:   1
|  bookmark:    master
```

I want to move my bookmark A down to changeset 3 and leave bookmark B at the current HEAD. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Should just be able to do

```
hg bookmark --rev 3 A
```

or if it complains

```
hg bookmark --rev 3 --force A
```

Try `hg help bookmark` for an explanation.